# HTML Not Parsed in Twitter's Bootstrap Tooltips

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mslinn/bFK5p/) to show the problem; I added all of the JavaScript and CSS files for my web page in the JSFiddle resources area. Here is the HTML from the JSFiddle:

```
<div class="date" title="Deadline for enrollment is 6 hours prior<br/>Session starts at 7/27/13 12:00 PM">2013/07/27<br/>12:00-12:50</div>
<div class="fqEntity" title="Slot #30 <b>Confirmed</b> <ol style='text-align: left'><li>Why can't we breathe CO2, like plants?</li><li>Why are these questions so silly?</li><li>What if we eat lots of chlorophyll?</li><li>Can't we just implant rebreathers?</li><li>What if we genetically engineered our skin to include chloroplasts?</li><li>Do you think green skin would be considered sexy?</li><li>Would short people be called 'little green men'?</li></ol>">course_ooCompat<br/>lecture_IDEA</div>
```

Here is the JavaScript from the JSFiddle:

```
$(function() {
  $('*').tooltip( { 
    html: true, 
    placement: bottom 
  } )
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the value of placement option should be a string (or function), so add quotes around it:

```
$(function () {
    $('*').tooltip({
        html: true,
        placement: 'bottom'
    })
});
```